# Jquery Mobile splash screen problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, splash-screen, iphone-standalone-web-app

I am working on a web app, and I am having an issue with the splash screen when you add the site to your homescreen. I've looked around and removed & re-added the line of code and it is still not working.

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="im/h-apple-touch-icon.png">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/loading-splash.png">
```

that is what i have in my head tag, and I'm just stuck as to why it will not work.

Comment: What exactly is the issue with the splash screen? Is it not showing up? Is it showing up and won't go away?

Comment: it refuses to show. i just get a white screen and then the app loads.

Comment: the link is http://kensingtonchurch.org/aaron_dev

Comment: Does this only happen when you are trying to access it from your iPhone? If so, set your iPhone to use WiFi and clear your cache before trying again.

Comment: yeah it happens when i use my iPhone or if i try from an iPad. I just cleared my cache and it still does not work. one thought i have is would the version of javascript that i have for jquery mobile?

Comment: jQuery Mobile is version dependent on jQuery. You must use the version of jQuery that your version of jQuery Mobile was designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you are getting a white screen is that the image you are trying to load does not exist on the server.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/loading-splash.png">
```

links to this address: http://kensingtonchurch.org/aaron_dev/img/loading-splash.png

I get a 404 when trying to find it.

---

Suggestions for debugging mobile apps:

- Install the User Agent Switcher for Firefox
- Install Firebug to trouble shoot.

Also, Opera has some sort of Remote debugging utility called Dragonfly. I've never used it, but it could be useful.

Comment: wow. i cannot believe that i missed that. Thanks for catching that.